# Select a random row based on a requirement from 50k rows table. Too slow. How can I speed it up?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with about 50k rows. There's a column called `status`. Its value can be either `0` or `1`. I need to grab a random row that has `status = 0`.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` is obviously too slow.

So, what I did so far was, get the count of the amount of rows that have `status = 0` using `SELECT COUNT(status) FROM table WHERE status = 0`

Now I now that I have 209 rows that have `status = 0`, but how can I work on these rows?

I'd would like to order these 209 rows, and make my php script get a random row number between the numbers 0 and 209, but I'm not sure how I can achieve that..

Comment: you should be able to just apply the `WHERE` clause to your original query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: "is obviously too slow" --- it shouldn't be for just 50k rows.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea yes I'm sorry, I had that already but I forgot to type it in.

Comment: @zerkms each row has 15 columns. I ran the query above earlier on phpmyadmin, it took 13 seconds to process. Did the same remotely, it took 53 seconds.

Comment: @viniciusmunich: if only 1 record is returned - I honestly cannot think of a reason for it to become 4 times slower remotely.

Comment: @viniciusmunich If randomizing a 50k row table takes 13-53 seconds that points to other problems. I just tried `ORDER BY RAND()` on a ~50k row table and it took 600-900ms, and that's on a relatively crappy VM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE status = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Sorting 209 should be quite fast.

EDIT:

Getting a random value efficiently is challenging.  If you have an index on `table(status)`, you can try an approach like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t cross join
     (select count(*) as allcnt from table where status = 0) const
WHERE status = 0 and
      RAND() < 10/allcnt
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

The `rand()` in the `where` clause is quite fast (`RAND()` is fast, sorting is slow).  It should greatly reduce the number of rows to an expected value of 10 -- which means that you are almost certain to get a row (99.99+%, I think) when you run it.  This is also simpler than the variable method.

The variable method involves a subquery, which incurs its own overhead for reading and writing the derived table.  The idea is to enumerate the rows and then choose one index randomly:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @rand := rand()) const
      where status = 0
     ) t cross join
     (select count(*) as allcnt from table where status = 0) const
WHERE floor(1 + @rand * const.allcnt) = rn;
```

Comment: Yes, that was fast, but every day at midnight, all rows get updated and their status is set to 0. So at midnight, the query would have to sork 50k rows. How fast would that be?

Comment: @viniciusmunich . . . As fast as your original query and quite different from the question you posted.  However, I have given three alternatives, one of which is necessarily fastest (among the three).

Comment: using the second method, my VPS load went from 0.10 to 129.90 until I restarted MySQL. The problem is that with every query, a string has to be decrypted (AES256), and I think that this is causing the high load.

Comment: The third method returned zero rows:

`MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.1686 sec)`

Comment: The third method returned no rows because I was missing the semicolon in the assignment to `@rand()`.  However, I don't think that will help  if fetching a single row has such a large overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this need two queries, but you can give it a try and benchmark it: get the total count of the rows that matches status = 0, get a random number from PHP between 0 and that number-1, do a select query with limit 1 and an offset of the random value generated by php.